# Paperclip with S3 -- AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, paperclip, aws-sdk

I am trying to use S3 as my host for Paperclip uploaded files. The S3 server is in China beijing region.

```
# Gemfile
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
gem 'paperclip', "~> 4.2"
```

I've setup AWS using environment variables.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: <access key>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: <secret key>
AWS_REGION: 'cn-north-1'
```

The AWS setup should be successful, because I'm able to create bucket in Rails console using

```
AWS::S3.new.buckets.create('dns-compat-bucket-name')
```

And my Paperclip config is as follow

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_host_name => 's3.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn',
  :bucket => 'superayi-prod-beijing'
}
```

However, I still get the error: 
`AWS::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId`

`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

Comment: can you check the permission in bucket policy.

Comment: Also where did you put your ENV varibales

Answer (score 0):

If you are using YAML file (settings.yml) and ENV variables for the configuration purpose then you have to use following syntax

```
development:
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>
```

As YAML files can understand code in ERB format and ruby code goes between <% and %>

Answer (score 0):

It ends up being that I have the following line in another file:

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'
```

This, for some reason, overwrites the settings in `development.rb`.

For people who are facing a similar problem like this, the following troubleshooting tips may be helpful:

1. As @Shrikant1712 suggested, the aws credentials have to be passed to Paperclip via the `:s3_credentials` option either as a file path or a Hash.
2. The `s3_host_name` should be a REST API endpoint which can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region). The endpoints of the China region are listed [here](http://docs.amazonaws.cn/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cnnorth_region).